# jQuery keyup, change is not working on strip form

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a web application using the Wordpress WooCommerce plugin. On the checkout page I want to check if all fields of a Stripe payment form are filled in, then enable a button which is disabled by default.

I found that the `keyup`/`change` events are not working. I tried to `alert()` but nothing happened. Here is what I tried up to now:

```js
jQuery(":input").bind("keyup change", function(e) {        
  alert('ok');
});
```

```js
jQuery(document).on('keyup,change', 'input.InputElement', function(e) {       
  alert('ok');        
});
```

If is OK, if it work only for keyup or only for change. I have also tried this

```js
jQuery(document).on('keyup','input.InputElement', function(e) {
  alert('ok');       
});
```

However it's not working.

Comment: The events passed to `on()` should be space delimiter, not comma. In other words, use `'keyup change'` instead of `'keyup,change'`

Comment: still not working. as I said I have tried on keyup but its not working. one thing to mention that form is loaded after an ajax request.

Comment: When you say 'it's not working' do you mean that you don't see the `alert()` at all?

Comment: yes, i don't see alert

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: no errors regarding this in console http://prntscr.com/l22gmr

Comment: You seem to have a couple of other errors in there though, which could well be interfering.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181277/discussion-between-rizwi-and-rory-mccrossan).